# flatten nested list by averaging vectors

Tags: r, list, nested, flatten

Say I have a nested list of vectors.

```
lst1 <- list(`A`=c(a=1,b=1), `B`=c(a=1), `C`=c(b=1), `D`=c(a=1,b=1,c=1))
lst2 <- list(`A`=c(b=1), `B`=c(a=1,b=1), `C`=c(a=1,c=1), `D`=c(a=1,c=1))
lstX <- list(lst1, lst2)
```

As seen, each vector `A,B,C,D` occur twice with `a,b,c` present in different frequencies.

How would be the most efficient way of flatten the lists so that `a,b,c` is summed, or averaged over `A,B,C,D` across the nested lists, as seen below. The real list has several hundreds of thousands of nested lists.

```
#summed
  a b  c
A 1 2 NA
B 2 1 NA
C 1 1  1
D 2 1  2

#averaged
  a   b   c
A 0.5 1   NA
B 1   0.5 NA
C 0.5 0.5 0.5
D 1   0.5 1
```

Comment: Are the values always `1`s?

Comment: For, example, does this works `res <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(unlist(lstX)), "\\.")) ; table(res[, 1], factor(res[, 2]))` ? or `table(res[, 1], factor(res[, 2]))/2` ?

Comment: I have both binary and weighted lists so something that works on both would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple base R solution (which will return `0` instead of `NA`s (not sure if good enough)

```
temp <- unlist(lstX)
res <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(temp), "\\.")), value = temp)
```

Sums

```
xtabs(value ~ X1 + X2, res)
#    X2
# X1  a b c
# A   1 2 0
# B   2 1 0
# C   1 1 1
# D   2 1 2
```

Means

```
xtabs(value ~ X1 + X2, res) / length(lstX)
#    X2
# X1  a   b   c
# A 0.5 1.0 0.0
# B 1.0 0.5 0.0
# C 0.5 0.5 0.5
# D 1.0 0.5 1.0
```

---

Alternatively, more flexible `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table) #V1.9.6+
temp <- unlist(lstX)
res <- data.table(names(temp))[, tstrsplit(V1, "\\.")][, value := temp]
```

Sums

```
dcast(res, V1 ~ V2, sum, value.var = "value", fill = NA)
#    V1 a b  c
# 1:  A 1 2 NA
# 2:  B 2 1 NA
# 3:  C 1 1  1
# 4:  D 2 1  2
```

Means

```
dcast(res, V1 ~ V2, function(x) sum(x)/length(lstX), value.var = "value", fill = NA)
#    V1   a   b   c
# 1:  A 0.5 1.0  NA
# 2:  B 1.0 0.5  NA
# 3:  C 0.5 0.5 0.5
# 4:  D 1.0 0.5 1.0
```

In general, you can use pretty much any function with `dcast`

Comment: the first solution is very slick. however, in a more general setting where negative values are allowed, the first solution allowing for `0`s instead of `NA`s is not ideal. i will sure to check `xtabs` out though! :)

Comment: Was about to post something similar. My starting point was: `data.table(nam = rapply(lstX, names), melt(lstX))`. +1

Comment: (Also, `xtabs` has a "data" argument, so you don't need to use `with`.) :-)

Comment: @AnandaMahto doh, forgot about it.

Comment: Awesome, so elegant! :-) I'll need to see which one is the fastest with really long lists.

Answer (score 2):

We could also try

```
library(data.table)
DT1 <- rbindlist(lapply(do.call('c', lstX),
            as.data.frame.list), fill=TRUE, idcol=TRUE) 
DT1[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), .id]
#   .id a b c
#1:   A 1 2 0
#2:   B 2 1 0
#3:   C 1 1 1
#4:   D 2 1 2

 DT1[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)/.N), .id]
 #  .id   a   b   c
 #1:   A 0.5 1.0 0.0
 #2:   B 1.0 0.5 0.0
 #3:   C 0.5 0.5 0.5
 #4:   D 1.0 0.5 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the shortest answer nor the fastest but we can try something like this:

```
### Get all the vector names
names <- lapply(lstX, function(l) lapply(l, names))
names <- unique(unlist(names))
names
## [1] "a" "b" "c"

## Check if a name is missing, for example
setdiff(names, names(lstX[[1]][[1]]))
## [1] "c"


## Now we will check for every vectors within each list
## and fill the missing names with NA and order the results
lstX <- lapply(lstX, function(l) {
  lapply(l, function(v) {
    v[setdiff(names, names(v))] <- NA
    v[order(names(v))] ## order by names to bind it without errors
  })
})

lstX
## [[1]]
## [[1]]$A
##  a  b  c 
##  1  1 NA 

## [[1]]$B
##  a  b  c 
##  1 NA NA 

## [[1]]$C
##  a  b  c 
## NA  1 NA 

## [[1]]$D
## a b c 
## 1 1 1 


## [[2]]
## [[2]]$A
##  a  b  c 
## NA  1 NA 

## [[2]]$B
##  a  b  c 
##  1  1 NA 

## [[2]]$C
##  a  b  c 
##  1 NA  1 

## [[2]]$D
##  a  b  c 
##  1 NA  1 


### Now we can bind it
matlist <- lapply(lstX, function(l) do.call(rbind, l))
matlist
## [[1]]
##    a  b  c
## A  1  1 NA
## B  1 NA NA
## C NA  1 NA
## D  1  1  1

## [[2]]
##    a  b  c
## A NA  1 NA
## B  1  1 NA
## C  1 NA  1
## D  1 NA  1


mysum <- apply(simplify2array(matlist), c(1, 2), 
           function(x) ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
mysum
##   a b  c
## A 1 2 NA
## B 2 1 NA
## C 1 1  1
## D 2 1  2


### Average over list
mysum / length(res)
##     a   b   c
## A 0.5 1.0  NA
## B 1.0 0.5  NA
## C 0.5 0.5 0.5
## D 1.0 0.5 1.0
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @CathG, you can create `matlist` quickly like this

```
matlist <- lapply(lstX, function(x) {
  t(sapply(x, function(y) {
    y <- y[names]
    names(y) <- names
    y
  }))
})
```

Comment: minor comment, you can get `matlist` with `lapply(lstX, function(x){t(sapply(x, function(y) { y <- y[names] ; names(y) <- names ; y}))})`, a it shorter